# Loop invariant for a division algorithm

Tags: algorithms, loop-invariants

I'm having problems trying to understand the concept of loop invariants.

I have the following code, where M and N are predefined constants.

```
a = 0
b = M
c = 1
while M - c * N >= 0:
  a = c
  c = c + 1
  b = M - a * N
print(a, b)
```

I have figured out this code is actually a division algorithm, where in the end prints out `a` as the quotient of `M/N` and `b` as the remainder. But it's unclear to me what the invariant here is. Can I say `c-a` is the invariant since `c-a=1` is always true before and after every iteration? How could I prove that in a mathematical perspective?

Comment: $c-a$ certainly is _an_ invariant, but it doesn't look like a very useful one, since the algorithm could easily be rewritten to use only $c$, and the fact that $c-a=1$ after each iteration doesn't really help you determine what the algorithm does.

Comment: Start by writing a formal postcondition in terms of $a,b$, preferably involving multiplication instead of quotient & remainder. Then try to modify that to involve $c$ as well, so that it is also true in the intermediate iterations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A loop invariant is an expression that is true through all iterations. But it should also lead to the post-condition being true when the loop terminates. Although c-a=1 is true, It doesn't help you in achieving the post-condition.

Intuitively, You would want the invariant to be `a*N + b = M` because that's what division is and that's what guarantees that you'll get the post-condition ( `a=quotient, b=remainder`) when the termination condition ( `b < N` ) is true.

The formal proof should follow from this idea.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $M$ and $N$ are both non-negative. There are a few invariants for the loop (we can verify them to hold prior to the loop, and after each iteration):

$P\colon M = aN + b$

$Q\colon c-a = 1$

$R\colon M-aN \ge 0$

Note, $P \land R \Rightarrow b \ge 0$

The loop's condition is:

$C\colon M-cN \ge 0$

$\Leftrightarrow M-(a+1)N \ge 0$  {due to $Q$}

$\Leftrightarrow M-aN \ge N$

Upon termination, $C$ is false, so following would hold:

$M-aN < N$

$\Leftrightarrow b < N$ {due to $P$}

Also,

$b \ge 0$ {due to $P \land R$}

So, $a$ and $b$ must contain the desired quotient and remainder ($0 \le b < N$) such that: $M = aN + b$.